# Does the max_allowed_packet variable have any effect on LOAD LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: mysql

As the question states, what (if any) is the effect of `max_allowed_packet` on `LOAD LOCAL INFILE`?

Does setting it to a large value load data files of large size such as 700MB into the db quickly?

Comment: Not posting as an answer b/c I don't know. But it seems like something you could easily test and report back on.

Answer (score 2):

LOAD DATA INFILE can be thrown off if [read_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_buffer_size) is larger than [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). This is the case when it comes to replication.

See the following bug reports

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15937
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30435
- http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/168070

Outside of MySQL Replication, I can't really tell.

One thing is for sure: Whatever mysql had as the setting for max_allowed_packet on a server that performed `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`, the server into which you import data via LOAD DATA INFILE better have the same setting for max_allowed_packet or greater.

The max value for max_allowed_packet is 1G. It couldn't hurt to just set that in my.cnf.

```
[mysqld]
max-allowed-packet=1G
```

You do not have to restart mysql. Just run this:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

then you can perform the LOAD DATA INFILE.

Answer (score 1):

There is no constraint like `"the loaded file must be < max_allowed_packet".`

You can load a GBs file.

**Depending on the size of the rows, you'll probably exceed this**.One way would be to split it up into several chunks. This is probably a good idea anyway.

**LOAD DATA** isn't subject to the `max_allowed_packet` limit.

If you are adjusting your `max_allowed_packet` (default is 1M).

Set it as

```
  SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet= 128 * 1024;
```

otherwise you may face the issue like

```
ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line : Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

If you face the above error set `max_allowed_packet` to some higher value.

Otherwise in my opinion increasing it to some higher value will not allow you to quickly load a 700MB file.