# Can I change max_allowed_packet for a MySQL database, but not others in the same instance?

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL server with multiple databases in the same instance. Can I change the max_allowed_packet value for just one of the database?

From looking at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html), it seems `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=xx` will affect the entire server while `SET max_allowed_packet=xx` will only affect the current session

Answer (score 1):

According to the MySQL Documentation on [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

> The maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string.
>
> The packet message buffer is initialized to net_buffer_length bytes,
>   but can grow up to max_allowed_packet bytes when needed. This value by
>   default is small, to catch large (possibly incorrect) packets.
>
> You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or
>   long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use.
>   The protocol limit for max_allowed_packet is 1GB. The value should be
>   a multiple of 1024; nonmultiples are rounded down to the nearest
>   multiple.
>
> When you change the message buffer size by changing the value of the
>   max_allowed_packet variable, you should also change the buffer size on
>   the client side if your client program permits it. The default
>   max_allowed_packet value built in to the client library is 1GB, but
>   individual client programs might override this. For example, mysql and
>   mysqldump have defaults of 16MB and 24MB, respectively. They also
>   enable you to change the client-side value by setting
>   max_allowed_packet on the command line or in an option file.

Based on this, your only chance to set it for your connection would be when starting the client program:

```
mysql -Dmydb --max-allowed-packet=1073741824
```

After all

- [max_allowed_packet is an option for mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_max_allowed_packet)
- [max_allowed_packet is an option for mysqldump client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet)

You cannot set it for the connection because it is a global option for how packets are used.

I just tried to run this in MySQL 5.6.15 for `Windows` and MySQL in `CentOS release 6.5 (Final)` and I got this message

```
mysql> set max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
ERROR 1621 (HY000): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value
```

Please read my posts on the MySQL Packet and its global effects

- `Apr 21, 2011` : [What does the MySQL “max_allowed_packet” setting actually control?](https://superuser.com/questions/273730/what-does-the-mysql-max-allowed-packet-setting-actually-control/273833#273833)
- `Apr 27, 2011` : [Changed max_allowed_packet and still receiving 'Packet Too Large' error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/886/changed-max-allowed-packet-and-still-receiving-packet-too-large-error/2383#2383)
- `Aug 01, 2011` : [How does max_allowed_packet affect the  backup and restore of a database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/how-does-max-allowed-packet-affect-the-backup-and-restore-of-a-database/4231#4231)
- `Feb 16, 2012` : [Does the max_allowed_packet variable have any effect on LOAD LOCAL INFILE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13160/does-the-max-allowed-packet-variable-have-any-effect-on-load-local-infile/13163#13163)
- `Aug 14, 2012` : ["Mysql has gone away" heavy multiple insert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22462/mysql-has-gone-away-heavy-multiple-insert/22464#22464)
- `Jul 03, 2013` : [What max_allowed_packet is big enough, and why do I need to change it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45665/what-max-allowed-packet-is-big-enough-and-why-do-i-need-to-change-it/45667#45667)
- [All my posts in the DBA StackExchange for max_allowed_packet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A877%20max_allowed_packet)